# MySQL Workbench Error during "Restore connections from a backup file"

Tags: mysql-workbench

I switched computers and I'm attempting to transfer my connections and server instances.

I created the backup.  On the new computer I go to **Tools > Configuration > Restore Connections** and select my zip backup.  However I get the following error...

[image]

I've Googled this issue and still can't figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I would raise this with mysql's support team as this is an error in a packaged software, not a code we can look at, debug and correct.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I face the same issue and it's really annoying.

Comment: No I haven't solved it yet

Answer (score 8):

BACKUP work-around for this bug:

- copy these two files: connections.xml and server_instances.xml
- location of these files (in windows) is: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench   (replace  with your own windows username)

Source: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102501

Comment: This worked for me, after installing a newer version. Thanks.

Comment: hero! saved me loads of time

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this issue while migrating between computers, which also resulted in my workbench being upgraded (6.3 on the source computer, 8.0 on the destination computer).  It looks as though it may be a version compatibility issue.   I uninstalled the 8.0 workbench and installed 6.3 and successfully restored the backup file.  Installing the 8.0 workbench performed an upgrade and left my newly imported configuration data intact on the new computer.

Comment: This worked for me on different versions of 8. I downgraded to 8.0.12, imported the connections then updated to 8.0.27. I tried doing a backup of the connections in the new version but get a "Backup file creation error - Could not create the backup file. Please check path and permissions and try again." I have tried several locations on my PC and all get the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem in version 8.0.25. I get the "could not create the backup file Please check path and permissions and try again" error when I try to backup my connections.

Comment: all great but how to know which version backup was made with?

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to migrate from 8.0.21 on a mac to 8.0.30 on windows. I uninstalled 8.0.30, installed 8.0.21 and imported the zip and boom all connections were available.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to gdet the same version of software where backup were created. So if you created backup on 8.0.22 and you try to resotre it on 8.0.27 you will receive the same error, but if you download 8.0.22 and will restore your backup on it, everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved! Version 8.30 | Windows 11 pro

1. - Default installation
2. - Extract files from backup and copy all the `.xml` files (connections, server_instances)  in

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench

3. - Reinstalling again with the Repair option

all connections backup were listed on MySQL workbench